# Display "Server running on port 5000 " on the console but canno't get

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-status-code-404, web-development-server

The API back-end has the following template:
[template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUylt.png)
The code for the back-end is the following:
Note that I changed the user and password for my own credentials on mangodb cloud.

**index.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';

import postRoutes from './routes/posts.js';

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '30mb', extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '30mb', extended: true }))
app.use(cors());

app.use('/posts', postRoutes);



const CONNECTION_URL = 'mongodb+srv://user:password@cluster0.fawpw.mongodb.net/authDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
const PORT = process.env.PORT|| 5000;

mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() => app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server Running on Port: http://localhost:${PORT}`)))
  .catch((error) => console.log(`${error} did not connect`));

mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
```

**controllers/posts.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

import PostMessage from '../models/postMessage.js';

const router = express.Router();

export const getPosts = async (req, res) => { 
    try {
        const postMessages = await PostMessage.find();
                
        res.status(200).json(postMessages);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
    }
}

export const getPost = async (req, res) => { 
    const { id } = req.params;

    try {
        const post = await PostMessage.findById(id);
        
        res.status(200).json(post);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
    }
}

export const createPost = async (req, res) => {
    const { title, message, selectedFile, creator, tags } = req.body;

    const newPostMessage = new PostMessage({ title, message, selectedFile, creator, tags })

    try {
        await newPostMessage.save();

        res.status(201).json(newPostMessage );
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(409).json({ message: error.message });
    }
}

export const updatePost = async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const { title, message, creator, selectedFile, tags } = req.body;
    
    if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) return res.status(404).send(`No post with id: ${id}`);

    const updatedPost = { creator, title, message, tags, selectedFile, _id: id };

    await PostMessage.findByIdAndUpdate(id, updatedPost, { new: true });

    res.json(updatedPost);
}

export const deletePost = async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;

    if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) return res.status(404).send(`No post with id: ${id}`);

    await PostMessage.findByIdAndRemove(id);

    res.json({ message: "Post deleted successfully." });
}

export const likePost = async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;

    if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) return res.status(404).send(`No post with id: ${id}`);
    
    const post = await PostMessage.findById(id);

    const updatedPost = await PostMessage.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { likeCount: post.likeCount + 1 }, { new: true });
    
    res.json(updatedPost);
}


export default router;
```

**models/postMessage.js**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    message: String,
    creator: String,
    tags: [String],
    selectedFile: String,
    likeCount: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: new Date(),
    },
})

var PostMessage = mongoose.model('PostMessage', postSchema);

export default PostMessage;
```

**routes/posts.js**

```
import express from 'express';

import { getPosts, getPost, createPost, updatePost, likePost, deletePost } from '../controllers/posts.js';

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', getPosts);
router.post('/', createPost);
router.get('/:id', getPost);
router.patch('/:id', updatePost);
router.delete('/:id', deletePost);
router.patch('/:id/likePost', likePost);

export default router;
```

****The problem is: when I run the command "npm start" on the server side the console displays "server running on port 5000" but when I open the link it displays the message " canno't get"(check the image attached). I checked if all the directories where correctly set up and I cant find the error! On the developer tools only output " error 404" ** Any idea?**

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuMpo.png)

[browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHPuo.png)

Comment: It output another error of  "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of favico.ico 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: The error regarding the favicon can be ignored. Browsers try to load the favicon but since this is an API  you don't need to provide a favicon.

Answer (score 1):

You added a router for `/posts` with

```
app.use('/posts', postRoutes);
```

You can access this router with

```
localhost:5000/posts
```

If you want to access this router with

```
localhost:5000/
```

you can add it with

```
app.use(postRoutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You mounted `postRoutes` to `'/posts'` endpoint. So whatever endpoint is specified in `routes/posts.js` it will extend on `/posts`. So when you do `getPosts()` it is not called on the `'/'` endpoint, but on the `/posts/` endpoint since the whole router is mounted to `'/posts'` endpoint.